# Passing a color through a variable in a canvas animation

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, rgb

I am attempting to make a customisable animation on a canvas.

I am trying to change the colour of the animation with the click of a button by passing through a different rgb value.

At the moment I am not getting any response to the click of the button

http://codepen.io/smbazalo/pen/RPrQRN

html

```
  <button onclick="changedotColor('rgb(63,169,245)')"  ><img  id="blue" class="swatch"></button>
```

js

```
var dotcolor_val = "rgb(6,250,212)";
function changedotColor(input_color){
dotcolor_val = input_color;
console.log(input_color)
}

function Circle( args ) {
this.position  = [ 0, 0 ];
this.angle     = 30;
this.speed     = dotSpeed;
this.offset    = 1;
this.length    = 80;
this.size      = 5;
this.color     = dotcolor_val;
this.direction = 'grow';
}
```

Any advice on what could make this work?//Why this isn't working currently?

Much appreciated

Comment: Based on the code you posted, `changedotColor` will update the `dotcolor_val`, but that doesn't update the color in `Circle` nor the color in the `canvas` context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the local variable `dotcolor_val` via the function `changedotColor()`, however, this variable's change of value is not being reflected in the `Circle` instances.

This is the link to the working code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPrQVW

### Explanation

In your code you are defining an object `Circle` with `function Circle(args)` with a few properties.

You are **instantiating** and pushing these Circle objects into 3 lists with the following code:

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  var offset = 1;
  rowOne.push(new Circle({
    angle: 0,
    offset: i
  }));
  rowTwo.push(new Circle({
    angle: 120,
    offset: i
  }));
  rowThree.push(new Circle({
    angle: 240,
    offset: i
  }));
}
```

`rowOne`, `rowTwo` and `rowThree` contain the Circle objects you have created. Thus, **one way** to change the color of your created Circles is to do 2 things:

1. Define a new function in the Circle object that will change the color of the object, as such:

   ```
   Circle.prototype.changeColor = function( rgbcolor ) {
       this.color = rgbcolor;
   }
   ```
2. When you trigger the function `changedotColor()` you need to iterate over the 3 lists and their children and trigger the `changeColor` function, as such:

   ```
   function changedotColor(input_color) {    
     for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       rowOne[i].changeColor(input_color);
       rowTwo[i].changeColor(input_color);
       rowThree[i].changeColor(input_color);
     }
   }
   ```

A different approach would be to modify your `render` method to take into consideration instance variable changes i.e. `color` value of the Circle object.